# How to put a lock screen with security code on a Arnova 10 G 2?

Tags: security, lock-screens

I have a Arnova 10 G 2 with Android 2.3 which works very well, but it has no unlock screen and no security options. Does anyone know of a way to put some kind of security code on the device, either swipe pattern or password or pin-code? I guess there must be some kind of simple app for this ...

Comment: So the device's "Settings" menu doesn't have the "Location and Security" list item?

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, but it has "Use Wireless Networks", "Set up SIM Card lock" (no idea why as it has no SIM slot), "Visible Passwords", "Select Device Administrators" and a section on "Credential Storage". Lock options are gone.

Comment: You could try installing some custom device lock app, like e.g. [Simply Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.firezenk.simplylock) (just to check whether this works -- if it does, you can browse the playstore for any app that may fit better :)

Comment: @Izzy Have you actually tried that lock screen app or did you just Google it? A bit unwilling to try one without knowing it's good first as if it breaks it's impossible to remove!

Comment: @James I didn't try it (mine works, and I don't want to replace it). Was just giving an example (the major point was a direction to a possible solution, not an app-recommendation). Of course it may be better to check reviews etc -- but a question like "what lock-screen to recommend" is OT here :) and I couldn't answer it...